# Is it possible to get html code in WebViewControl in Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webview

Just like in the WebBrowser controller, the following code can be used to retrieve the html code. I've tried everything but I haven't found anything like that for WebView Controller

```
webBrowser.DocumentText
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, for a *webView1* control in Winforms with the *Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView* package :

```
webView1.NavigationCompleted += new System.EventHandler<Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.WebViewControlNavigationCompletedEventArgs>(this.webView1_NavigationCompleted);
```

and :

```
private async void GetPageHTML()
{
    sHTMLSource = await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
}

private string sHTMLSource = null;
private void webView1_NavigationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.WebViewControlNavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    GetPageHTML();
}
```